# Segue from TableView to Navigation Controller in Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, uinavigationcontroller

I currently have a navigation controller that directs to the table view that displays all the people I'm currently chatting (ChatroomTableViewController). Once I click one of the messages in my table view, I'm brought into the actual message and into a view controller (MessageViewController).

**Problem**: I now need a back button MessageViewController, which means I now need to add a navigation controller. This is my current code (for without a navigation controller in front of MessageViewController):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let messagesVC = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MessageViewController") as! MessagesViewController
    //Some code here
    let room = results?.last as! PFObject
    messagesVC.room = room
}
```

Instead of instantiating MessageViewController, I want to instantiate the navigation controller that will point to MessageViewController.

**Attempt**:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let messagesVC = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NavigationViewController") as! UINavigationController
    //Some code here
    let room = results?.last as! PFObject
    messagesVC.room = room //ERROR! "UINavigationController does not have a member named 'room'"
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
let navigationVC = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NavigationViewController") as! UINavigationController
let messagesVC = naviagionVC.viewControllers[0] as! MessagesViewController
let room = results?.last as! PFObject
messagesVC.room = room
```

This is assuming that your MessagesViewController is the `rootViewController` of your design.

**EDIT**

Here is how navigation controller works: Suppose you have a hierarchy of view controllers: AViewController - BViewControler - CViewController which you would want to embed in a navigation controller. What you do is, you create a navigation controller and make `AViewController` the `rootViewController` and then "push" `BViewController` and later `CViewController`. Both `BViewControler` and `CViewControler` will get back buttons; `AViewController` doesn't since it is the root.

In your case, the VC which has the table view should be the `rootViewController`. And on tap of the cell, you should push the `MessagesViewController` which will have a back button, on click of which it will pop to your current view controller.

Comment: It compiled fine, but I still don't seem to get the back button on my MessagesViewController. I'm assuming the nav controller wasn't called properly. And yes, my MessagesViewController is the 'rootViewController'.

Comment: You wouldn't get a back button if MessagesViewController is the `rootViewController`. Since, you know, it IS the rootViewController. There is nothing to go back to. :)

Comment: What I did: made a Navigation controller and made it point to MessagesViewController, thus making that the rootViewController. I thought if I made that the rootViewController of the navigation controller, I would get a back button. Was I supposed to do something else? Sorry for sounding like an amateur, and appreciate your help. Started Swift less than a month ago :p

Comment: I understand. Here is the updated answer for you. :)

Comment: Issue #2: can you also explain why I'm getting different results when I do different pushes/presents?                

`//This has a back button with no message functionalities
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(messagesVC, animated: true)

//This has no back button but has message functionalities
self.navigationController?.presentViewController(messagesVC, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: You use a navigation controller in places where there is master-detail system. Eg., your iPhone contacts screen, you have a list of contacts which is the master and the detail -- the specific detail about the master that will show up when you tap on a contact. Presentation is different. In the contact detail, you have an edit icon, on click of which a screen with a different screen will appear which isn't a part of the navigation. You don't go "back". You are just done with editing. :)